# Jquery clone array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to clone a div with inside a "select" and then have the possibility to get info about it after submit the form.

```
<div id="cloneDiv" style="display: none"><select name="test[]">
<option value"test1">test</option>
</select>

<div class="option">...</div>

$( ".cloneDiv" ).clone().insertBefore( ".option" ).show();
```

I am not able to get information about the new test[] created.

Thanks

Comment: The new `test[]`? What do you expect from your form submit exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class or an id to the element when you clone it so you can differentiate it from everything else you have.

maybe something like:

```
$( ".cloneDiv" ).clone().insertBefore( ".option" ).addClass("myClass").show();
```